# Automation of Zoom classes on python

Tags: python, pandas, pyautogui

how to change the code such that it can connect for 5 minutes, I mean if I have a class at 8:30 and turn my laptop on at 8:32, it can still connect to the class (I have never done this, trust me).

```
import pyautogui
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


def sign_in(meetingid, pswd):
    code_path = r"C:\Users\vnsin\AppData\Roaming\Zoom\bin\Zoom.exe"
    os.startfile(code_path)
    time.sleep(2)

    join_btn = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('join.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(join_btn)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(1)

    meeting_id_btn = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('meeting_id_button.png', confidence=0.6)
    pyautogui.moveTo(meeting_id_btn)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.write(meetingid)
    time.sleep(1)

    join_btn = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('join_text.png', confidence=0.6)
    pyautogui.moveTo(join_btn)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(5)

    meeting_pswd_btn = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('meeting_pswd.png', confidence=0.6)
    pyautogui.moveTo(meeting_pswd_btn)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.write(pswd)
    pyautogui.press('enter')


df = pd.read_csv('timings.csv')

while True:
    # checking of the current time exists in our csv file
    now = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
    if now in str(df['timings']):
        row = df.loc[df['timings'] == now]
        m_id = str(row.iloc[0, 1])
        m_pswd = str(row.iloc[0, 2])
        sign_in(m_id, m_pswd)
```

Comment: You can scan through the file once before you enter the loop, and process any events that occurred before the current time.

Answer (score 1):

**Side note**: Wouldn't it be easier to use the webbrowser module (builtin) and the links for your zoom classes instead of all the image locating and pandas dataframes? You could simply create a dict with timings and links, and open the links in your preferred browser.

Here is code that returns `True` if the time now if both after the class time and within `x` minutes. I know it's ugly, but it works.

```
def is_after_minutes(now, tyme, minutes): # now: time_right_now, tyme: class_time, minutes: time program should join late
    if ((now[:2] == tyme[:2]) and (int(now[2:]) - int(tyme[2:])) in list(range(0, minutes + 1))) or ((int(now[:2]) - int(tyme[:2]) == 1) and (60 + int(now[2:]) - int(tyme[2:]) <= minutes)):
        return True
    return False
```

You could also use an `elif` statement for this, but that's up to you.

This also works if `now`(time right now) and `tyme`(class time) are the same. However, it will not return True if `now < tyme` (this is expected behavior, nobody wants to join class early :)). If you want your bot to join the class as long as `now` is **within** `minutes` of `tyme`, use code below:

```
def is_after_minutes(now, tyme, minutes):
    if ((now[:2] == tyme[:2]) and abs((int(now[2:]) - int(tyme[2:]))) <= minutes)\
            or ((int(now[:2]) - int(tyme[:2]) == 1) and (60 + int(now[2:]) - int(tyme[2:]) <= minutes)):
        return True
    return False
```

Tell me if this is not what you need (or some other issue) in comments.